# ffmpeg conditional filtering

Tags: ffmpeg, video, image-filter

i'm using ffmpeg to process a video.  ideally, i'd like to apply one filter chain if the image in question is predominately a dark monochrome, and a different filter chain for other images.

it seems to me that this isn't possible exactly; it looks like a conditional can be used as part of an expression of a given filter, but can't determine the execution of an **entire chain**. (is this correct?)

assuming it is, it seems that i should nevertheless be able to use the same conditional repetitively in each element of the filter chain so that some elements will actually change the output while others will do nothing.

i've found the `entropy` filter that seems to identify well enough the images where i'd like to apply one filter instead of another, but i can't figure out how to use the value this filter calculates in the conditional elements of my filter chain, rather than simply having it print the values to the console.

one example of how i'd like this to work conceptually might look like this:

```
-filter_complex "...,dilation=threshold0=(if(gt([entropy],0.8),100):threshold1=(if(gt([entropy],0.8),100):threshold2=(if(gt([entropy],0.8),100):threshold3=(if(gt([entropy],0.8),100), ... "
```

is something like this possible?  if so, how could i go about doing it?  if not, is there some other way to get the results i'm looking for?